# Elbow Method for optimal no. of clusters

Tags: clustering

I have a dataset that I am analysing to find the optimal number of clusters using k-means.

I am testing the number of clusters from [1..11] - which produces the following plot:

[image]

The original dataset has six classes but the elbow plot shows the bend really occurring at 3 clusters. For curiosity I overlaid a line on the plot from 11 clusters and back and it is almost a straight line to 6 clusters - which indicates to me that the real elbow is at 6, but it is subtle to see.

So, visually 3 looks to be the right answer, but given the known number of classes (6) the straight line I drew indicates 6...

Question:

- How should you correctly interpret an elbow plot like this
  (especially when you are not given the classes)?
- Would you say the
  elbow is at 3 or 6?

Comment: Using the Elbow method to determine the no of clusters is not a preferred way as there is usually no distinctive "knee" in the plot. If you have some previous knowledge about the data (somewhat similar to the idea of semi-supervised learning), then you may use that to determine the no of clusters. As you already know there are six classes in the dataset, then you should use 6 clusters, not 3.

Comment: Thanks Imran. "As you already know there are six classes in the dataset, then you should use 6 clusters, not 3" Fair enough, but what I have above is just an example to illustrate the point of the question. The question is "If I want to use the elbow method and I do not know the number of clusters, what is the most correct way to find the elbow?"

Answer (score 0):

As your question implies, it can be difficult to determine the number of clusters from an elbow plot as it is a heuristic approach rather than an exact method.

In the past I have used [Cluster Evaluation By Prediction Strength](https://www.stat.washington.edu/wxs/Stat592-w2011/Literature/tibshirani-walther-prediction-strength-2005.pdf) with some success. There is an accessible intro to this in [this blog post,](https://towardsdatascience.com/prediction-strength-a-simple-yet-relatively-unknown-way-to-evaluate-clustering-2e5eaf56643) along with Python code. Some R code is available at [this github](https://github.com/echen/prediction-strength). I have also written some R code for my personal use in the one dimensional case which is available in one of my blog posts [here](https://dekalogblog.blogspot.com/2020/11/temporal-clustering-part-3.html).

Answer (score 0):

The correct way to find the optimal clusters depends on a couple of things. your reasearch question, proportion of the instances in the cluster, elbow method,  you can also try silhouette method. You can also say 6 clusters from your graph because the graphs is still droppping at 3. Relatively, it is straightening out at 6. It all depends on what exactly you want to explore.!